# rootView is displayed but isShown() method returns false

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `Fragment`, and in `onActivityCreated` i check whther or not the `rootView` of the `fragment` is shown or not using `isShown()` method. Although the layout is displayed, this line returns `false`

```
Log.d(TAG, "is rootView isShown: " + rootView.isShown());
```

**Code**:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.w(TAG, "@onCreateView()");
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mqtt_fragment, container, false);
    initModeChooseViews(rootView);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.w(TAG, "@onActivityCreated()");
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "is rootView Shown: " + rootView.isShown());
}
```

Comment: use `setMenuVisibility`, override that and check boolean value

Comment: at this stage of your rootView still not visible, try to check in `onResume` method

Answer (score 0):

call it in `OnResume()` because `isShown()` *Returns the visibility of this view and all of its ancestors* . *Returns True if this view and all of its ancestors are VISIBLE*

From reading, if you have setVisibility of a view in relation to this to not-visible, is going to return false, so check if you have toggled visibility of a related view or call it when everything is visible which is onresume

Comment: ok, is there any way to convert or to cast a layout to view? for an example, given the layout "r.layout.myLayout" i want to convert it to a view so that i can use the methods ishown(), isClickanle(),,...and so on

Comment: you are using fragments right? its already being done, just use `getView()` it returns the rootview of the fragment passed in at `onCreateView` there you can call `View` defined functions like `isShown()` @rmaik  for eg, `if(getView().ishown())`

Answer (score 0):

you check visibility too early. In onActivityCreated method fragment's view isn't visible yet. Fragment view become visible since fragment's onStart. So check visibility in onStart method (or any other place after onStart).